# How to increase the range of ports available to services in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, ports

I want to create a loadBalancer service on kubernetes that exposes a large range of ports. As you can't do that on kubernetes yet (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23864).

I have manually entered a range of port by having a yaml file in the following format:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: port10000
  port: 10000
  protocol: UDP
    .
    .
    .
  - name: port40000
  port: 40000
  protocol: UDP
  selector: 
    app: app-label
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I get the following error:

> Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "service-udp.yml": Internal error occurred: failed to allocate a nodePort: range is full

Is it possible to increase the range of ports available for a service? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled by the `--service-node-port-range portRange` argument to `kube-apiserver` - the way to change that depends on your environment.

Keep in mind that nodePorts are meant to be used by load balancers as building blocks. So what you are trying to do is most likely not the best practice.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks @JanosLenart, I'm on the google cloud platform, do you know how to change the kube-apiserver --service-node-port-range portRange on it?

Comment: If you are running on GKE (managed kubernetes cluster) then there is no way to change it

Comment: To update the kube-apiserver, edit the file under `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`. Its been watched and the pod will be rebooted.